# C program stops after traing to access string array

Tags: c

i'm making a program in C that let the user insert the number of names that he wants, this names is stored in a global array and then they are printed, but the program finishes before, specifically when i try to access to the global array to print the names to show them to the user. I need to have my global array as follows: char *array[10]. This problem just happens when i use the previus syntax, but when i use: char array[10][], all runs fine, what's the problem here? somebody can help me please, i have tried so many hours.

CODE:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX 10
int counter = 0;
char *concts[MAX];

void add_2(char *name){
    printf("Se anadira un elemento en el index %d\n", counter);
    concts[counter] = name;
    counter++;
}

void main(){
    char *name;
    int ingresando = 1, i;

    do{
        printf("ingresa un nombre: ");
        scanf("%s", &name);
        add_2(name);
        printf("Seguir ingresando? ");
        scanf("%d", &ingresando);
    }while(ingresando == 1);

    printf("Terminado. contador: %d\n", counter);

    for(i = 0; i < counter; i++){
        char *otherName = concts[i];
        printf("%s\n", otherName);
    }
}
```

PROBLEM:
I don't really know, but the program ends before what is expected, it compiles well and does not prompt errors.

EDIT:
The program stops after print "Terminado. contador: %d\n"

Comment: Compile with `-Wall`. Also you never initialise `name`.

Comment: what will be your input and expected output on that input?

Comment: Because `*concts[MAX]` is an array of pointers those pointing to no  allocated memory, so you should allocate memory for each pointer or just declare it for example like `char concts[MAX][20]`

Comment: `name` is a pointer and can't store a string, use an array of chars instead.

Comment: *"it compiles well and does not prompt errors."*  Compile with `-Wall -Werror` to fix that false perception.

Comment: thanks to everyone, then it will work if i assign memory to the array, something like: `char *concts = malloc(some size)` ?

Comment: No that allocates memory for one string. For multiple strings, you either need to `malloc` memory for each string, or declare a 2D array. For example `char concts[10][32]` gives you room for 10 strings of 32 bytes each. And `char *name` should be `char name[32]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here I made some changes

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX 10
int counter = 0;
char concts[MAX][20];

void add_2(char *name){
    printf("Se anadira un elemento en el index %d\n", counter);
    strcpy(concts[counter], name);
    counter++;
}

int main(){
    char name[20];
    int ingresando = 1, i;

    do{
        printf("ingresa un nombre: ");
        scanf("%s", name);
        add_2(name);
        printf("Seguir ingresando? ");
        scanf("%d", &ingresando);
    }while(ingresando == 1);

    printf("Terminado. contador: %d\n", counter);

    for(i = 0; i < counter; i++){
        char *name = concts[i];
        printf("%s\n", name);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Make sure you only enter names up to 19 characters.

Comment: Yeah I don't know how much chars he expects but it's up to him to decide, for me it's just an example, he can change the size the way he need

Comment: Note: You don't need the `&` when giving a string argument to `scanf`; `scanf("%s", name);` will do.

Comment: Ah I'm sorry I didn't even see it, because I was focusing on the main problem, thanks I have just edited the answer

Comment: Thanks, this answere works well for me, ran fine and does what i expected.

Answer (score 1):

Now run it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
void add_2(char *name); //defining prototype of function
#define MAX 10
int counter = 0;
char concts[MAX][20];
void add_2(char *name){
    printf("Se anadira un elemento en el index %d\n", counter);
    strcpy(concts[counter], name);
    counter++;
}
main(){
    char name[20];
    int ingresando = 1, i;
    do{printf("ingresa un nombre: ");
        scanf("%s", &name);
        add_2(name);
        printf("Seguir ingresando? ");
        scanf("%d", &ingresando);
    }while(ingresando == 1);
    printf("Terminado. contador: %d\n", counter);

    for(i = 0; i < counter; i++){
        char *name = concts[i];
        printf("%s\n", name);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The above answers seem right but the other way is using malloc.

first you must include <stdlib.h> and then edit line 12(char *name) like this

```
char *name=malloc(21);
```

*for old version of gcc you must cast the output of malloc to char *